# Button showing/hiding parametr LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, button, onclick

Hi :) I am new in programming and salesforce.
and now i have a problem with buttons. I want to one click it and show a param from js (data).

(company.date schould show just when I will click button)

Can u help me write a right method?

**Place of parametr data**

```
<lightning-datatable data={companys.data} columns={columns} key-field="Name"></lightning-datatable>
```

**Button**

```
<div class="slds-col">
                        <lightning-button 
                        label="Search"
                        onclick={}
                        variant="brand"></lightning-button>
                     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript controller needs a property to show/hide the element:

```
showCompanies = false
```

Elements can use that controller property, so they will be shown only when `showCompanies` is `true`:

```
<lightning-datatable if:true={showCompanies} ...
```

The button has a number of *events* it can dispatch. An event is just a message from where an event originates, such as a button click or typing on the keyboard, letting another component know that something interesting happened. In this case, we use `onclick`:

```
<lightning-button onclick={showSearchResults} ...
```

Which is then written in your controller class:

```
showSearchResults(event) {
  this.showCompanies = true;
}
```